# Rails race condition uniqueness intersection dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, unique, conditional-statements, race-condition

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve race condition in this scenario.

**I am using rails 3.2.11 with active record**

I have the models: (just an example)

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  attr_accessible :start_date, :end_date, :person_id
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

The problem is:

I want to ensure that one person only have 1 task assigned between that interval (`start_date` and `end_date`)

For example,

```
Task | Person_id | start_date       | end_date
0      1           01-01-01 10:00     01-01-01 11:00
1      1           01-01-01 10:15     01-01-01 10:45  ## this should no be valid!!
```

I know that validations in Rails don't prevent this because of race conditions, and I cannot add index at database level because I dont want the `unique => true` but instead some sort of `unique_in_interval => true`

Could someone explain how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you the idea, use `after_create` callback to check the uniqueness of the field just inserted during that conditional interval.

So in your tasks model,

```
attr_accessor :between_date

after_create :discard_insert


def discard_insert
    @same_records = Person.joins(:tasks).where(:tasks=> {:between_date => start_date..end_date})
end
```

The above method will give you all the records with the race conditions and than you can delete the later one.

Answer (score 1):

Just lock the operation using any locking mechanism like [redis locker](https://github.com/einzige/redis-locker)

```
RedisLocker.new("assign_task_#{@user.id}").run! do
  @user.assign_task(@task) unless @user.has_task_within_time_period?
end
```